# How to add Nil to UIAlertAction

Tags: swift, null, uialertaction

I have to put Nil to `getIDColor`, but I don't know right way to do that.

```
var getIDColor: Int?

let colorButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Select Color", style: .default) { _ in
    self.openColorTVC(categId: self.getIDColor)
}
```

Comment: do you mean like `var getIdColor: Int? = nil`?

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking. Your example is creating an alert action with a handler closure that calls your `self.openColorTVC(categId:)` function. If your `openColorTVC(categId:)` function's categId parameter is an Optional, you could change the body of the closure to `self.openColorTVC(categId: nil)`, but I'm not sure if that's what you are asking.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

```
following the answer by Farhad Bagherzadeh I used guard statement for categId

func openColorTVC(categId: Int?) {
        guard categId != nil
        else {
            return openColorTVC(categId: 1)
        }
        if let checkColorId = categId {
            let colorSB = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            
            if let destinCSB = colorSB.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "colorsID") as? ColorsTVC {
                destinCSB.categorColors = checkColorId
                navigationController?.pushViewController(destinCSB, animated: true)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean how to define a func with optional parameter, here is the answer:

[image]

Comment: func openColorTVC(categId: Int?) {
        guard categId != nil
        else {
            return openColorTVC(categId: 1)
        }
        if let checkColorId = categId {
            let colorSB = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            
            if let destinCSB = colorSB.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "colorsID") as? ColorsTVC {
                destinCSB.categorColors = checkColorId
                navigationController?.pushViewController(destinCSB, animated: true)
            }
        }
    } Thank you Farhad!